# Why does my pygame object vibrate instead of moving smoothly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Firstly, I'm very new to coding so if my code looks terrible, that's why

I'm trying to use PyGame to spawn 10 balls that spawn in random locations and move in random vectors. When each of the ball hits the edge of the screen, it'll bounce back.

The problem with the code that I have below is that the balls do spawn fine, the balls do bounce back from the window just fine, but the balls only move along the x-axis (left and right) but vibrate on the y-axis (up and down). I have no clue why this is happening.

My code is as follows:

```
from random import randint, choice
import pygame
pygame.init()

## -- set constants
white = [255, 255, 255]
black = [0, 0, 0]
grey = [255/2, 255/2, 255/2]

ball_fill = white # colour of balls or circle objects
ball_line_colour = ball_fill # border and fill of same colour

n_balls = 10 # number of balls on a window
ball_radius = 12 # size of balls in pixels

velocity = vel = {
    "x": randint(-2, 3),
    "y": randint(-2, 3)
    } # must range from -a to +b; otherwise will only move rightward and upward

## -- set display window

win_width = 800 # pixels; width of screen
win_height = 600

## -- Define the boundaries, that is, the points at which the balls would bounce back without going out of the window

boundary_location = ['up', 'down', 'left', 'right']
boundary_coord = [ball_radius, (win_height - ball_radius),
                  ball_radius, (win_width - ball_radius)]

boundary = dict(zip(boundary_location, boundary_coord))

## -- Define balls
class Ball():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

def make_ball():
    """
    Function to make a new circle or ball
    """

    ball = Ball()
    # spawn points of balls, so that the balls do not overlap when they spawn

    x = randint(boundary["left"], boundary["right"])

    ball.x = choice([n for n in range(int(boundary["left"]), int(boundary["right"]))
        if n not in range(x - ball_radius, x + ball_radius)])

    y = randint(boundary["up"], boundary["down"])

    ball.y = choice([n for n in range(int(boundary["up"]), int(boundary["down"]))
        if n not in range(y - ball_radius, y + ball_radius)])

    # Speed and direction of rectangle

    ball.change_x = vel["x"]
    ball.change_y = vel["y"]

    return ball

# Set the height and width of the screen

win_dimen = [win_width, win_height]
win = pygame.display.set_mode(win_dimen)

pygame.display.set_caption("Multiple Object Tracking")

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

ball_list = []

for i in range(n_balls):
    ball = make_ball()
    ball_list.append(ball)
    i -= 1

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # --- Event Processing
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    # Space bar or esc to exit
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE or event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                done = True

    # --- Logic
    for ball in ball_list:
        # Move the ball's positions
        ball.x += ball.change_x
        ball.y += ball.change_y

        # Bounce the ball if needed
        if ball.y > boundary["up"] or ball.y < boundary["down"]:
            ball.change_y *= -1
        if ball.x > boundary["right"] or ball.x < boundary["left"]:
            ball.change_x *= -1

    # Set the screen background
    win.fill(grey)

    # Draw the balls
    for ball in ball_list:
        pygame.draw.circle(win, white, [ball.x, ball.y], ball_radius)

    clock.tick(60)

    # Update the screen
    pygame.display.flip()

# Close everything down
pygame.quit()
```

My next step is to make the balls bounce off each other, in case anyone is wondering

Comment: `boundary["up"]` and `boundary["down"]` are inverted, so ` if ball.y > boundary["up"] or ball.y < boundary["down"]:` is always `True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic for checking up/down boundaries is reversed, so the vibration happens because the balls are constantly out of bounds and have their y velocities inverted on every frame. If you change the line:

```
if ball.y > boundary["up"] or ball.y < boundary["down"]:
```

to:

```
if ball.y < boundary["up"] or ball.y > boundary["down"]:
```

you'll be all good.